# How to call and pass array of string and find the length of that array inside the function

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am writing a program to check if a string is inside an array of strings.
I predefined an array of words before the main method

```
const char *items[] = {"a","b","c","d"};
```

then I have a function like

```
bool isInside(const char *array[], char *s1){
 //which will try to compare all strings from the input array with s1
  int len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
  for (int i =0; i< len ; i++){
   //do string comparasion}
}
```

It worked before but not sure where I messed up the code now I got two errors and the function is only able to check the first string of the array with s1.

I found out the problem is that now len = 1 always.

one of the errors is

```
`warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘array’ will return size of ‘const char **’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]` and the other one is 

isInside(items, words[i]))
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~
      |                               |
      |                               const char **
code.c:63:21: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char **’
```

How can I fix this or call this function so the length is correct and no type warning?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the type of `words`?

Comment: Just pass the array length.  C doesn't pass arrays or returns them from functions, so it's impossible to know the size of an array if you don't pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C will degrade to pointers when passed as arguments to functions. When they become pointers, their length cannot be retrieved by `sizeof`.

You should pass the length of arrays as an additional argument to the function.

Maybe your function can be modified as:

```
bool isInside(const char **array, int arrayLength, char *s1){
  for (int i =0; i< arrayLength; i++){
     const char* str = array[i];
     if(strcmp(str, s1) == 0){
        return 1;
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I did using a marco to fix this issue like you said. Now I wonder why it worked before. LOL